# npm install github repo strips src folder

Tags: node.js, github, npm

I did the following:

```
npm install TuningGuide/react-sortable-hoc --save
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@3.10.5
npm info using node@v6.2.2
npm info git [ 'clone',
npm info git   '--template=/Users/velten/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates',
npm info git   '--mirror',
npm info git   'git://github.com/tuningguide/react-sortable-hoc.git',
npm info git   '/Users/velten/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-tuningguide-react-sortable-hoc-git-78a804e9' ]
npm info git [ 'rev-list', '-n1', 'master' ]
npm info git [ 'clone',
npm info git   '/Users/velten/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-tuningguide-react-sortable-hoc-git-78a804e9',
npm info git   '/var/folders/95/ylk5ht9s24n6xk4rcr6sch4r0000gn/T/npm-22395-24e6f9cc/git-cache-220f34bb/09fb1e0c7d657657b9aa091c018b45aee0ed0662' ]
npm info git [ 'checkout', '09fb1e0c7d657657b9aa091c018b45aee0ed0662' ]
npm info git [ 'submodule', '-q', 'update', '--init', '--recursive' ]
npm info attempt registry request try #1 at 14:18:51
npm http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/invariant
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/invariant
npm info lifecycle invariant@2.2.1~preinstall: invariant@2.2.1
npm info lifecycle react-sortable-hoc@0.0.7~preinstall: react-sortable-hoc@0.0.7
npm info linkStuff invariant@2.2.1
npm info linkStuff react-sortable-hoc@0.0.7
npm info lifecycle invariant@2.2.1~install: invariant@2.2.1
npm info lifecycle react-sortable-hoc@0.0.7~install: react-sortable-hoc@0.0.7
npm info lifecycle invariant@2.2.1~postinstall: invariant@2.2.1
npm info lifecycle react-sortable-hoc@0.0.7~postinstall: react-sortable-hoc@0.0.7
typescript-react-mobx-boilerplate@1.0.0 /Users/velten/Websites/typescript-react-mobx-boilerplate
└─┬ react-sortable-hoc@0.0.7  (git://github.com/tuningguide/react-sortable-hoc.git#09fb1e0c7d657657b9aa091c018b45aee0ed0662)
  └── invariant@2.2.1 

npm info ok
```

[image: folder]

But the folder does not contain the source nor the build. Why?

Comment: See https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2974

Comment: Did you try reinstall it? Is it the same result?

Comment: `npm cache clean` and reinstall it.

Comment: @WilfredHughes your referenced issue is not related. npm does not download the src subdirectory. As you can see the package.json is in the root directory.

Comment: Found the relevant issue: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3055

Comment: I will clone the repo into a vendor folder now and then npm i && npm run build

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`src/` is banned in the .npmignore folder (if we talk about [this repo](https://github.com/clauderic/react-sortable-hoc/blob/master/.npmignore))

```
https://github.com/clauderic/react-sortable-hoc/blob/master/.npmignore
```

...and the implicit `prepublish` triggers `build` only on a regular “published install”, *not* if you install directly from github... (also learnt that the hard way).

Try with any wellknown package, by not installing it in the standard way but from github directly, to verify.

Painful, indeed. Best thing one can do on his own repos is to use the "preinstall" hook. (And not ban the `src/`-Folder for it, to work).

You could clone the repo, allow src/ folder (remove from .npmignore), and move build-process to "preinstall" hook...

Comment: Any advice on how to "move build-process to "preinstall" hook..."?

Comment: Yes, would be great to hear something about that.

Answer (score 3):

You may need to set `files` in package.json for your repo.

Comment: Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Curiously, NPM 10 is stripping the `lib/src` dir from one of my deps. This worked fine before in NPM 9 (`lib/src` was not stripped). Adding this solved the issue for NPM 10: `"files": [ "lib", "lib/src" ],`

Answer (score 0):

One workaround to get the entire repo contents is to install from an archive, for example (looks like the repo was renamed `clauderic/react-sortable-hoc` since the question was asked)

`$ npm install https://github.com/clauderic/react-sortable-hoc/archive/v0.6.7.tar.gz`

This downloads `src/` but not `build/` which is not tracked in git.