# Build NPM package installed from git

Tags: git, npm, npm-install

I want to install the [npm diff package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/diff).  The package as published on npm does not work with latest version of babel.  The repository has been [updated](https://github.com/kpdecker/jsdiff/commit/a47aca9cb199d558e02ce406e9838356803e204f) to fix the problem.  I want to install diff from github.

Following the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43847785/556635) and [here](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3055) I [forked](https://github.com/calcbench/jsdiff) the repo and removed src from the .npmignore.

After I run `npm install git+https://github.com/calcbenc
h/jsdiff.git` node_modules/diff exists without the lib and dist directories.

How do I "move the build-process to the 'preinstall' hook" so that the package is built during the install process?

I tried using https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-git-install, but it did not build the package after install.

Answer (score -2):

I've fixed the same problem like this:

1. Remove your current `node_modules` folder.
2. Remove the required module from your `package.json`.
3. Run `npm install` in your project directory.
4. Now, install the required module with the following command: `npm install --save https://github.com/{Username}/{Repository}/tarball/{Branch}`. Fill in the {Variables} as needed.
5. Navigate from your project folder to `node_modules/{Required Module}`.
6. Run `npm install` inside the required modules folder.
7. Finally, build it with `npm run build`.

That should work.

Cheers
Unkn0wn0x

Comment: Lucky are the ones who give you negative feedbacks, but don't write clearly how to do that properly...